# VB.Net anomalous conversion to string

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, double, scientific-notation

We have a VB.Net app uses the following expression:

```
CStr(CDbl(Now.ToOADate()))
```

(The code was ported from VB6.)  I tested it a few hours ago it evaluated/rendered as "42026.786202581" exactly as it should. But is some small number of cases (I can tell from data) it renders as "42026.786202581E+15".

That of course is a very wrong result, the integer portion is the number of days since 1/1/1900 and 42K is a rational value, it doesn't need to be multiplied by anything (forget 10^15th!)

You may have noticed it's using VB6 compatibility, the old type coercion functions, I changed it to:

```
Convert.ToDouble(Now.ToOADate()).ToString()
```

But I couldn't reproduce it in the lab anyway, so output unchanged, as expected... The binary format of OADate actually is identical to double float, should be a no-brainer as far as conversions go...

Bottom line, I can't even imagine how such a simple expression could be off by 15 orders of magnitude!  Any insight appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Calling CDbl is redundant.  The `ToOADate` method already returns a double.  Why are you converting it to a string?

Comment: If you convert an OADate to string it renders a date and time string, you have to convert/cast to double to render a floating point formatted string.

Comment: The string is used as a uniquifier -- I know, I know, use a GUID instead.  I'm just trying to understand how the problem as manifested was possible.

Comment: OADate has the same binary format as a double, but there are operators and other class code associated with the type, that necessitate the conversion/cast.

Comment: You're suggesting that `CDbl` somehow changes the Double returned by `ToOADate`?  When I tested, I got the same values.  `DateTime.Now.ToOADate()` returned _exactly_ the same value as `CDbl(DateTime.Now.ToOADate())`.  Calling `CDbl` in this situation is clearly redundant.  I'm not sure what you think the extra call to `CDbl` changes.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking OADate was a type.  (It certainly wasn't redundant in VB6.)  So converting a double to a double is a no-op, how does this pertain to my question?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that issue, but have you checked out your regional settings? I suspect implicit date/number/string conversion problem, something related to bad-interpreted decimal point (that "42026.786202581E+15").
Have you checked your regional settings?
Why you force ToOADate() to double if it's already a double? Try this and tell me what you get:

```
    Dim a As Double = Now.ToOADate()
    Dim str As String = a.ToString()
    Debug.Print(a) ' Datetime to Double
    Debug.Print(str) ' Double to String
    Debug.Print(CDbl(str)) ' String to Double
```

I got this answer (please note my system is set to Italian, so I get comma instead of a point):

```
42027,5610133565
42027,5610133565
42027,5610133565
```

Do you have different result formats?
If not, you should investigate more about that "some small number of cases" and report when/where you have such exp value (and sure it was exactly "E+15" with 4 integer digits?)!